# Display several html pages in single webbrowser when respective button clicked?

Tags: c#, xaml, navigation

I have 100 html files. I know how to initialize the `<phone:webBrowser />` for single xaml page. But, If I used this method, then i need to create 100 xaml pages by initializing webbrowser in it and i can navigate that xaml page by button click. But, its waste of time.

So, I created `<phone:webBrowser>` in `webview.xaml` and 100 buttons in `chapters.xaml`

What i am asking is, if `button1` pressed in `chapters.xaml`, `chapter1.html` should be open in `webview.xaml`. if `button2` pressed in `chapters.xaml`, `chapter2.html` should be open in `webview.xaml`. like this, all 100 files should be open in `webview.xaml` by respective button click in `chapters.xaml`. how to open?

My `chapters.xaml` page :

```
<Button Content="Chapter 1" Click="webview"/>
<Button Content="Chapter 2" Click="webview"/>
/.../
<Button Content="Chapter 100" Click="webview"/>
```

My `chapters.cs` page:

```
private void webview(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/webview.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

My `webview.xaml` page:

```
<phone:WebBrowser x:Name="browser" IsScriptEnabled="True" Margin="-12,0,-11,0" />
```

I don't what to give in `webview.cs` page, help me what to give in cs page to open html pages ? Thanks in advance.!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may attach the appropriate HTML file name with each Button by setting its `Tag` property:

```
<Button Content="Chapter 42" Tag="chapter42.html" Click="webview"/>
```

Then use the [Navigate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff403407.aspx) method of the WebBrowser control:

```
private void webview(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;
    var htmlFile = (string)button.Tag;
    browser.Navigate(new Uri(htmlFile, UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Of course you may also construct the proper file name from the `Content` string of the Button (at least it looks like). Then there would be no need to set `Tag`.

Comment: how it will be open in `webview.xaml` ?

Comment: Simply by having a WebBrowser control named `browser` in `webview.xaml` as you've shown in your question. What's your point?

Comment: i would request you to answer for me for (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18484028/wpf-wp8-change-textblock-content-by-respective-button-click)[this]

Comment: That's not the way it works here. You can't request or demand something.

Comment: anyway thanks @clemens. you code works with small modifications. thank you so much. i have updated the working answer here.