# C# - wp8: change textblock content by dynamically?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have several html files in my app. I displayed it through webBrowser. I stored that current displaying page's number as `string Page`. I wanna display that page name in textblock. So, I have stored those text as string's. For example

```
string chapter1 = "Welcome page";
string chapter2 = "About us";
//...// 100 strings
```

If welcome page is displayed in webbrowser, the `string page` will be 1. by using `string page` `string chapter1` should be `fileName.Text` likewise i wanna display. but, I dunno how to do so. Best answers will be much appreciated.

C# Code;

```
TextBlock fileName = new TextBlock();
fileName.Margin = new Thickness(0);
fileName.FontSize = 30;
fileName.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
fileName.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
fileName.Text = "???";
```

Comment: if you are using html, how come you have tagged it c#?

Comment: i was displaying html contents thru webBrowser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I done it using `switch` statement. Anyway thanks for all

Answer (score 1):

If your `XAML` controls are labelled [have the **Name** tag], then you can call them from C# like this:
**XAML:**

```
<TextBlock Name="fileName" Margin="0,0,10,0" FontSize="30" Foreground="White" TextAlignment="Center" />
<phone:WebBrowser x:Name="browser" IsScriptEnabled="True" /><br>
```

**C#: [assuming you have a button]**

```
btn_Click+=(s, args) => {
fileName.Text="NewText";
}
```